# Does gelatin in vitamins make them haram?

Tags: halal-haram, medical

I purchased [cod liver oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cod_liver_oil) capsules and it has [gelatin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin). I was told by my elders that it's haram. I don't know why and how, but people in Muslim countries have not that much awareness or they sell vegan cod liver oil. What should one do in this kind of case when your not sure. To eat or not to eat? As many items in European countries have unknown stuff which can be haram for Muslims e.g supplements.

Comment: i wish i was in your position. For me, its the other way around, in which i'm always telling my parents what's halaal and not, and boy have i gotten into huge fights over it (my dad especially). Just keep your heart pure, and for the sake of Allah SWT, and you wont find it a problem looking for what's  halaal and haraam

Comment: I fail to see how it is haram if you have to take cod liver oil for the benefit of your health. @TashannaChamma Based on your answer, do you also not consume modern medicine? Many medicines contain alcohol.

Comment: this is a controversial topic, but if there is absolutely no alternative, and you absolutely need it, then it should be fine. there would be many other companies that make cod liver oil, and some may not use gelatin, it's all about you doing your research for the sake of Allah, and In Sha Allah you will find something that will benefit you both in this world and the hereafter.

Comment: @TashannaChamma that's just cherry picking then isn't it? I'll take the medicine because it makes me feel better, but I wont have the cod liver oil? I am not talking about a serious illness. What about a cold or a fever where you don't absolutely need medicine, but if you take medicine, it will make you feel better. But chances are you are ingesting alcohol. There is a word for this, i think its a double standard. yup.

Comment: @masfenix if you are that concerned about taking your time to choose a halaal product over haraam, then why dont you just ask your religious leader if it's ok? there are always alternatives for everything, and dont forget you've got the natural medicines too. Unless it's a life or death matter, then i dont see why someone would want to go for a haraam product when they know there could be halaal alternatives, especially when it has been mentioned many times in the quran to stay away from that which is haraam. And what exactly do you mean by double standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any product you buy, you usually find these additives like gelatin, emulsifiers, etc. No matter what the product is, so long as it is not halal, then that entire food becomes not halal. Regarding gelatin, emulsifiers, and other additives that originate from animals, they usually use pig fats for them, but many companies also claim to use beef or other animal fats. As a muslim, your job is to call up the company and make sure that the additives are firstly not originated from pig, and secondly, if it is (say for example) beef gelatin, then you need to make sure it comes from an animal that has been slaughtered accordingly with islamic shariah. this is a big topic, and there are many disputes regarding all the conditions, but just remember that this life is a test, and so even if everything has haraam additives, there are still alternatives, which if you seek for the sake of Allah, He will reward you (In Sha Allah). Try your best to consume that which is halaal, and not haraam, as you will be asked about it on the day of judgement, and Allah SWT knows best.

oh and to summarise and answer your question, dont eat it if your in doubt, just call up their company and ask them where their gelatin originates from, and if they say beef then ask if you can have the contact number for the company that supplied them the gelatin. then call the gelatin company and ask if they are halaal certified :)